# How to import cookies from a netscape cookies.txt file and use them?

Tags: c++, asp.net, cookies, libcurl

I'm really new to LibCurl, and I have some cookies in a netscape cookies.txt file, which I need to make the program recognize and do some functions which can only be done with does cookies
e.g.

```
http://foo.com/foo.asp?user=Foo
```

Without the cookies, it would return:

```
loggedin=no
```

With the cookies, it would return:

```
loggedin=yes
```

How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEFILE) is what you're looking for. Just write your simple libcurl app, point out the cookie file with this option and it'll read and use those cookies in the request(s).